# How to run a powershell script from javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me with a javascript to run a powershell script?
The both files are on the same local machine.

Comment: node-powershell is your friend :)

Answer (score 1):

I  assume you are referring to server side javascript(node.js)
you can use `.exec()` function in the `child_process`  module . eg

```
require('child_process').exec('ls',
    function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log( stdout);   

        if (err) {
             console.log('Error ' + err);
        }
    });
```

will run the `ls` command