# in javascript how to call powershell script

Tags: javascript, powershell

I have a powershell script and I run on powershell like :

> .\download-packages-license.ps1

But I want to call the javascript file before these lines.

```
var json =fs.readFileSync('../../dev/licenses/AllLicenses.json', 'utf8');
var options = {compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4};
var result = convert.json2xml(json, options);
```

I could not anything in stackoverflow except : [How to run a powershell script from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479448/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-javascript][1])
So pls help thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work for you -

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
spawn("powershell.exe",[".\download-packages-license.ps1"]);
```

Comment: @Rithest Singh Rajput it is my fault.The code run but powershell script is not worked . My code create a new txt file . Created file is empty. I checked again when i run on command line txt is not empty.

Comment: It  worked for powershell you are right @Ritesh Singh Rajput

Answer (score 2):

You can work with : [Node-Powershell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell)

Code Snippet :

```
const Shell = require('node-powershell');

const ps = new Shell({
  executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
  noProfile: true
});

ps.addCommand('echo node-powershell');
ps.invoke()
.then(output => {
  console.log(output);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: example call only comment how i call  my download-packages-license.ps1 @Amit Baranes

Comment: I wrote  `const ps = new Shell({
        executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
        noProfile: true
      });
      
      ps.addCommand('./download-packages-license.ps1'); `  but terminal work forever @Amit Baranes

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

JScript

Simple way.

Works great. Suitable for simple operations, but loses some data when receiving line feeds as a single \n instead of the expected \r\n. Split by \r\n misinterprets the array which leads to the need to reformat the array of strings. Basically, I just wrote this, so there may be other problems.

```
var codepage='windows-1251';/*US-Europe-1252 and Js file in that codepage*/
var toPStext='Hello.\nПроверка русских буковок.';
var shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var std=shell.Exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command \
    $OutputEncoding = [Console]::outputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('"+codepage+"'); \
    Write-Output '"+toPStext+"'");
var output = std.StdOut.ReadAll().split('\r\n');// split('\n') - leads to the loss of some data
if (output.length>0){WScript.echo(output)}
//var x=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```

Line by line.

Unfortunately, powershell does not accept external data as sequences of lines, unlike cmd.exe with /q /k options, which simplifies this code, but will turn around problems with multiline output code. Of course, if necessary, you can transfer the code as a base64 string to powershell

```
var codepage='windows-1251';/*US-Europe-1252 and Js file in that codepage*/
var toPStext='Hello.\nПроверка русских буковок.';
var shell=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var output=[],errors=[],WshRunning=0,WshFinished=1,WshFailed=2,i=0,tryCount=0;
var std=shell.Exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command \
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::outputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('"+codepage+"'); \
Write-Output '"+toPStext+"'");
do{
    if (std.Status==WshFailed){
        errors.push('String '+i+' data read error: \n   '+std.StdErr.ReadLine());
        tryCount++
    }
    else if(std.Status==WshRunning){
        output.push(std.StdOut.ReadLine());
        tryCount=0;
        WScript.Echo('Running ...')
    }
    else if(std.Status==WshFinished){
        var last=std.StdOut.ReadLine();
        if(last.length>0){output.push(last)};last=undefined;
        tryCount=21;
        WScript.Echo('Finished ...')
    }i++;
}while(tryCount<21);        
if (output.length>0){WScript.echo(output)}
if (errors.length>0){WScript.echo(errors)}
var x=WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
```