# Dynamic XML Element Using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

So lets get an example going lets say you have this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <KeyEvents>
        <num_events>4</num_events>
        <event_1>
            <distance>0.044</distance>
        </event_1>
        <event_2>
            <distance>0.055</distance>
        </event_2>
        <event_3>
            <distance>3.778</distance>
        </event_3>
        <event_4>
            <distance>3.822</distance>
        </event_4>
        <Summary>
            <total_distance>7.699</total_distance>
        </Summary>
    </KeyEvents>
</test>
```

The issue is each XML file will be different and have a different number of event_[x]. So in essence there could be 4, 300 or even none.

So here would be the model.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
public class test {

    private int numEvents;
    private Event event;
    private Summary summary;

    public static class Event {
        private double distance;

        @XmlElement(name = "distance")
        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }
    }

    public static class Summary {
        private double totalDistance;

        @XmlElement(name = "total_distance")
        public double getTotalDistance() {
            return totalDistance;
        }
    }
}
```

The end goal is to iterate over all the "events" and get each distance from each event and just print them to console (there will always be one Summary).

I've tried storing events as a map. Example:

```
private Map<String, Event> events;
```

But I can't seem to unpack and iterate over all the events. Any help? Appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)

$keyEvents = $doc.Descendants("KeyEvents")[0]
$events = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($keyEvents.Elements(),  [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x[0].Name.LocalName.StartsWith('event')})

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($event in $events)
{
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
      Name = $event.Name.LocalName
      Distance = $Event.Element('distance').Value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$summary = $keyEvents.Element('Summary').Value
$newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
   Name = 'Summary'
   Distance = $summary
}
$table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

$table
```

Results

```
Name    Distance
----    --------
event_1 0.044
event_2 0.055
event_3 3.778
event_4 3.822
Summary 7.699
```

Comment: As useful as this would be I'm more so looking for a Java JAXB-only solution. I highly appreciate the code though, I did try and it works but it would make a lot of spaghetti code in my project to implement.

Comment: You could run code from Java as a shell command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002794/in-javascript-how-to-call-powershell-script  Or you can create a CSV from PS

Answer (score 0):

For me you're missing two things :

The `test` tag has only one element, which is `KeyEvents`.

The `KeyEvents` then have `numEvents`, `summary` and the `event_XXXX` tags.

To catch the `event_XXXX` tags, you should try using the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation.

You'd have something like this in final model :

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
public class Test {
   @XmlElement(name = "KeyEvents")
   private KeyEvents keyEvents;

   public static class KeyEvents {
        @XmlElement(name = "num_events")
        private int numEvents;
        @XmlElement(name = "Summary")
        private Summary summary;
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        private List<Event> events;
    }

    public static class Event {
        private double distance;

        @XmlElement(name = "distance")
        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }
    }

    public static class Summary {
        private double totalDistance;

        @XmlElement(name = "total_distance")
        public double getTotalDistance() {
            return totalDistance;
        }
    }
}
```